# Outlook form field value in body

Tags: outlook

I am decent at programming VB for Excel but this is the first time I have tried Outlook.  What I am trying to do is create a form that allows me to fill in some data and have that info be populated into the body of an email which would be sent to someone else.

I, and others, handle cell phone replacement requests for a large company.  When we have info about the shipping we send an email to the end user to give them instructions on how to activate and set up the phone.

The email we fill in has about 6 things that we replace in the email multiple times.  I am hoping to make a form where we fill in that data once and it applies the changes to the body.

One section looks like this (it shows most of the fields in one place):
Mobile: xxxx
Model: xxxx
Tracking Number: xxx
Order Type: xxx

I have designed the form and have custom fields for the data to be placed in.  I am not finding how to get the data from the form placed in the body of the email in the places where it is needed.

If anyone has a website that shows how or anything I would be grateful.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: You will need to Create an email message template and then replace xxxx with form data

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Do you mean that I have to create the template before the form and then make the form off the template?